# How to display things programmatically in the panel?

Tags: unity, gnome, panel

I want to integrate my app into the Unity/Ubuntu top panel by being able to output some small printed messages or icons or indicators to the panel. Some of my programs that I have installed do this, for example, Redshift has a button, and the gnome-system-indicator (system load indicator) outputs a CPU usage graph.

[image: Redshift example]

How can I access this programmatically, so that I can have my own program print data to the panel in the same way as something like gnome-system-indicator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called unity indicator. There is page on Ubuntu website: [appindicator](https://unity.ubuntu.com/projects/appindicators/). Have a look on it. I think it gives you enough information.